# Static variable messing everything up

Tags: java, java-2d

Probably a very basic Java problem but I have two variables in a entity class:

```
public class Entity {

int posX;
int posY;

public Entity(int posX, int posY){
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
}

public void update(){

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){

}
```

}

My player and enemy class extend it and then render off of the two variables. Like so:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImg(), posX, posY, null);
    if (showBounds == true) {
        g2d.draw(getBounds());
    }
}
```

I need to access these variables like this (This is in my enemy class):

```
public static void moveFemale(){
    if(posX <= Player.posX){
        //do AI code
    }
}
```

posX And Player.posX throw an error saying I need to change the modifier of posX in Entity.java to static. But when I change it to static, my renderer for the enemy class stops working and the enemies no longer show up on screen. How could I go about creating a variable that allowed me to do this:

```
public static void moveFemale(){
    if(posX <= Player.posX){
        //do AI code
    }
}
```

And still render my enemies? Sorry for the wall of text and any answers would help a lot!

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about the keyword `static` and decide if you really need to have your methods declared as `static`.

Comment: I'm guessing this is what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320190/java-extended-static-class-of-a-non-static-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `moveFemale` method is static so it needs to know *which* female to move. Either pass in a reference to the palyer or find a may to make the move methods non-static member methods of the player.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should remove modifier `static` from method `moveFemale`

```
 public void moveFemale(){
    if(posX <= Player.posX){
        //do AI code
    }
  }
```

Comment: Player.posX should not be accessed in a static way since it's not static.

Comment: Andrew suggest good thing to pass player as param to this method. Than you will be able to get player's position from it.

Comment: @opiop65: What do you mean by "wants to be"? How much do you understand about what `static` means?